# ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required (X_train)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, optimization, scikit-learn, feature-selection

The following code:

```
def FN1(I,trainInput,trainOutput,dim):
         reducedfeatures=[]
         max_fold=3
         cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=max_fold,shuffle=True,random_state=20181224)
         fold_N=0
         headers = list(trainInput.columns)
         Accuracy= np.zeros((max_fold))
         min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    
         for index in range(0,dim):
           if (I[index]==1):
               reducedfeatures.append(index)

         X=trainInput.iloc[:,reducedfeatures]
         y=trainOutput

         bag = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
         for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
             X_train, X_test =  X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
             y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
             X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
             X_test = min_max_scaler.transform(X_test)
        
          
         bag.fit(X_train, y_train)
         bag_test_pred = bag.predict(X_test)
         acc = accuracy_score(y_test, bag_test_pred)
         Accuracy[fold_N]= acc
         fold_N = fold_N +1             
        

         acc_train = float(Accuracy.mean())
         fitness=0.99*(1-acc_train)+0.01*sum(I)/(dim)

         return fitness
```

when call the function==> FN1(I,trainInput,trainOutput,dim)

I==> [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1., 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1., 1. 1. 0.]

---

trainInput is a Dataframe (3662,51)

trainInput Values==> 0          1         2   ...         48         49         50 [0     121.494292  22.721127  0.187014  ... -13.057328  65.886200  -5.045918] [1     117.662500  11.651773  0.099027  ...   8.196990  54.899022   6.697461] [2     127.768910   6.139864  0.048054  ...  -0.596537  55.917289 -93.736531] [3     121.495203  21.577174  0.177597  ... -25.979896  77.973068  -3.001285] [4     121.767437  21.096243  0.173250  ... -23.498519  74.947541  -3.189458] [...          ...        ...       ...  ...        ...        ...        ...] [3657  127.556197  16.297749  0.127769  ... -17.448701  62.277666  -3.569186] [3658  124.642494  17.864664  0.143327  ... -11.217407  56.090017  -5.000266] [3659  125.934417  10.930816  0.086798  ... -12.221817  60.637324  -4.961400] [3660  127.470093  11.174433  0.087663  ... -15.660888  67.215756  -4.291951] [3661  127.203900   3.159062  0.024835  ...  -6.664322  77.234556 -11.589259] [] [[3662 rows x 51 columns]]

---

trainOutput is an ndarray (3662,)

trainOutput ==> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

---

dim ==>  51

Gives the error message:

```
V.VVVV.V is optimizing  "FN1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\main.py", line 69, in <module>
    x=slctr.selector(i,func_details,PopulationSize,Iterations,completeData)
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\selector.py", line 69, in selector
    x=ssaelo.SSAELO(getattr(fitnessFUNs, function_name),lb,ub,dim,popSize,Iter,features,labels)
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\SSAELO.py", line 255, in SSAELO
    SalpPositions[:, i] = main(objf, N, Max_iteration, 0.5, 0.5, lb, ub, trainInput, trainOutput, dim)
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\SSAELO.py", line 118, in main
    obj = [cal_obj(pop[i], trainInput, trainOutput, dim) for i in range(npop)]  # objectives
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\SSAELO.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    obj = [cal_obj(pop[i], trainInput, trainOutput, dim) for i in range(npop)]  # objectives
  File "C:\Users\sa\Desktop\ISSAA\fitnessFUNs.py", line 49, in FN1
    X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
  File "C:\Users\sa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 852, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\sa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 416, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\sa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 453, in partial_fit
    X = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\sa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 566, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\sa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 665, in check_array
    dtype_orig = np.result_type(*dtypes_orig)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in result_type
ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required
```

It seems that the error is in this line:
X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used (copied from yours), and created a dataset using sklearn and then tested it

```
import pandas as pd,numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def FN1(I,trainInput,trainOutput,dim):
    reducedfeatures=[]
    max_fold=3
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=max_fold,shuffle=True,random_state=20181224)
    fold_N=0
    headers = list(trainInput.columns)
    Accuracy= np.zeros((max_fold))
    min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

    # for index in range(0,dim):
    # if (I[index]==1):
    #     reducedfeatures.append(index)
    reducedfeatures = (I == 1).nonzero()[0]

    X=trainInput.iloc[:,reducedfeatures]
    y=trainOutput

    bag = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
    for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X,y):
        X_train, X_test =  X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test = min_max_scaler.transform(X_test)


    bag.fit(X_train, y_train)
    bag_test_pred = bag.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, bag_test_pred)
    Accuracy[fold_N]= acc
    fold_N = fold_N +1             


    acc_train = float(Accuracy.mean())
    fitness=0.99*(1-acc_train)+0.01*sum(I)/(dim)

    return fitness
```

```
# trainInput,trainOutput,dim = ()
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

trainInput, trainOutput = make_classification(5000, 50, n_informative=4,n_classes=5)
trainInput = pd.DataFrame(trainInput)

print(trainOutput.shape, trainInput.shape)

# output
# (5000,) (5000, 50)
```

```
spam = np.array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1. ,1., 1., 1. ,1., 1., 1., 0.,
 1. ,1. ,1. ,0., 1. ,1. ,1. ,0. ,0., 1. ,1., 1., 0.,
 0., 1. ,1., 0. ,1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1. ,1., 0.])

FN1(I=spam,
   trainInput=trainInput,
   trainOutput=trainOutput,
   dim=51)
# output
# 0.8873309323729491
```

It seems to be working correctly for me.

Try to convert the data into dataframe or numpy array and then try it.

There is also possibility that there is missing values.